# Convert to full unicode string

Tags: php, json, unicode, unicode-escapes

How can I convert a string from `\uD83D\uDE00` to full `\U0001f603`?
`json_encode()` only converts to the first option...

```
$str = '';
$encode = json_encode($str);
var_dump($encode);

// string(14) ""\ud83d\ude03""
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a built in function for that, so you should roll your own, maybe using preg_replace_callback.. However, what is the use case here? You mention JSON, but JSON can't use the `\U` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the `Intl` extension installed, this is easy enough to do with one of its [built-in transliterators](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-ICU-Transliterators):

```
<?php
$str = "";
echo transliterator_create("Any-Hex/C")->transliterate($str);
```

Output:

```
\U0001F603
```